# Setar localStorage em diferentes domains

Tags: node.js, angular, express.js, localstorage

Tenho três aplicações:

**1. Login (que roda na porta 8080) com jQuery bem simples**

**2. API (que roda na porta 4000) com Nodejs**

**3. Web (que roda na porta 4200) com Angular**

Quando estou no login e clico em "Entrar", vai chamar a API, validar se o usuário existe, se sucesso vai retornar um token do JWT. Quando retorna esse token, preciso setar ele no localStorage, pra depois redirecionar para a aplicação web.

O problema disso, é que são portas diferentes, se eu setar no localStorage da aplicação do login e depois redirecionar para a aplicação web, o token não vai mais existir no localStorage.

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

A API `localStorage()` é executada pelo navegador sobre a "[Politica de Mesma Origem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)" (Same-Origem) por isto mesmo que a aplicação rode em um mesmo domínio (example.com) portas e subdomínios são tratados como origens diferentes.

Para contornar isto você pode trabalhar em alguma solução que faça uso de `<iframe>` e `postMessage()` para poder sincronizar o dados de `localStorage()`.

Existem diversas bibliotecas que faze exatamente isto como por exemplo a [Cross Domain Local Storage](https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage) contudo, se seu único intuito é conferir o **"token"** simplesmente salve este **"token"** em um `cookie` que ele estará disponível para todo domínio, subdomínios e portas.

Vale lembrar que "tokens" JWT possuem marcação de tempo para validação bem como você poderia criar alguma base para controlar "tokens" expedidos e já utilizados.

Você pode remover o `cookie` assim que utilizar o "token", se for usar esta abordagem não esqueça de usar (caso em produção) um `cookie` sobre as bandeiras `HTTPONLY` (apenas para o servidor), `SECURE` (apenas sobre TLS) e até mesmo `SAMESITE`.

Comment: E ai Lauro. Não gostei muito da idéia de usar <iframe> para sincronizar os dados. Você acha mesmo uma boa prática?

Vou dar uma olhada nessa biblioteca que você comentou.

Comment: Não, pode ser dificil manter, depurar e se você precisar um CSP mais restritivo fica difícil... terá que criar regras para quais páginas usar ou não um `<iframe>` é viável más, acho que se você só quer o token será mais fácil usar cookie mesmo

Comment: Eu cheguei a usar a muito tempo atrás algo que achei e modifiquei...se eu encontrar em meus documentos envio para um Gist GitHub e adiciono um link aki... pode ter alguma utilidade dentro do scopo da questão más não recomendo para transitar um token de acesso

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Uma abordagem que eu gosto de fazer quando preciso centralizar certos dados para que haja "apenas uma fonte de verdade" é utilizando redis, com ele fica muito tranquilo de vc ter várias aplicações que podem consumir e alterar dados que estarão disponíveis para todos os clientes.